# How to edit ylab2 on doubleYScale?

Tags: r, lattice

i need edit to `ylab2` in `latticeExtra::doubleYScale`. How your observe in Figure, the legend of axis y and axis y2, haven different size. How i can put the same size (`cex=1.4`)?

[image]

script:

```
require(latticeExtra)
require(reshape2)
require(grid)
require(gridExtra)

dados<-melt(clima[,c(1,3:5,8)], id.vars=1,measure.vars=2:4)
 dados$data<-ymd(dados$data)



lat1<-
  xyplot(value~data, groups=variable,data=dados,
       scales=list( x=list(at=dados$data,labels=format(dados$data,"%d/%m"))),
               type=c("l","p"),pch=c(15,16,17),lty=c(1,2,4),lwd=2,col=c("blue","red","black"),
             ylim =c(0,35),xlab="",ylab=list(expression("Temperatura ("^"º"*"C)"),cex=1.4),
             key=list(columns=1,space="bottom",
                      text=list("Tmáx"),lines=list(col="blue",type="b",lty=1,pch=15,lwd=2),
                      text=list("Tmín"),lines=list(col="red",type="b",lty=2,pch=16,lwd=2),
                      text=list("Tméd"),lines=list(col="black",type="b",lty=4,pch=17,lwd=2)))


lat2<-
barchart(P~data,data=clima,scales=list( x=list(at=dados$data,labels=format(dados$data,"%d/%m"))),
              horiz=FALSE,ylim=c(0,10),col="purple",
               xlab="",ylab=expression("Precipitação (mm d"^-1*")"),
               key=list(columns=1, text=list("P"),space="bottom",rectangle=list(col="purple")))

update(doubleYScale(lat1, lat2, add.ylab2 = TRUE,use.style = F))
```

when i use : `lat2::ylab=list(expression("Precipitação (mm d"^-1*")"),cex=1.4)`, the program change the legend for "P".

I tryed use `trellis.par.set(axis.text=list(cex=1.2))`, but this only change size of numbers in axes.